# Easier way to enforce typed immutable data structures?

Tags: immutable.js, flowtype

Enforcing a data structure with vanilla JS objects and flow is easy:

```
type ExampleObjType = {
  key1: number,
  key2: string
};

const obj: ExampleObjType = {
  key1: 123,
  key2: '123'
};
```

It seems like this requires an unnecessarily large amount of boilerplate to enforce a similar structure in Immutable:

```
type TestSpec = {
  key1: number,
  key2: string,
};

const TestRecord = Record({
  key1: 0,
  key2: '',
});

const record: TestSpec & Record<TestSpec> = new TestRecord({
  key1: 123,
  key2: '123',
});
```

Further, the above structure has some major drawbacks:

- Forced default values
- No enforcement on invalid keys on initialization, only on access

Ideally I would be able to use `Immutable.Map`, something like this:

```
type TestSpec = Map<{key1: number, key2: number}>;

const testMap: TestSpec = Map({
  key1: 123,
  key2: '123',
});
```

However, the current implementation only allows typing of key and value type. I could constrain the key type using something hokey like `type Key = 'key1' | 'key2'`, but that still wouldn't me to explicitly type the values per key.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for with Immutable? It seems like a very foundational requirement to true type safety, particularly when used for, say, Redux action payloads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`immutable.Record()` is difficult to type. In fact, [it's currently typed](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow#L625) to return `any`. On one hand, this is inconvenient, since you'll need to describe the type of `TestRecord` from scratch. On the other hand, it lets you type it however you like!

Here's one option:

```js
interface TestSpec {
  constructor(defaults: $Shape<TestSpec>): void,
  key1: number,
  key2: string,
};

const TestRecord: Class<TestSpec> = Record({
  key1: 0,
  key2: '',
});
```

The `Class<TestSpec>` type is the type of a class who's instances have the type `TestSpec`. You don't have to define the constructor in `TestSpec`, but by doing so, Flow will make sure `obj` has the right time when it sees `new TestRecord(obj)`.

(Note: `$Shape<TestSpec>` is the type of an object which may or may not have. So in this case it basically means `{key1?: number, key2?: string}`)

```
new TestRecord({key1: 123,  key2: '123'}); // OK
new TestRecord({key1: 123}); // OK
new TestRecord({key2: '123'}); // OK

new TestRecord({key2: 123}); // Error number -> string
new TestRecord({key1: '123'}); // Error string -> number
new TestRecord({key1: 123,  key2: '123', key3: 'blah'}); // Error unknown property key3
```

And Flow will check that instance properties have the right type

```
const record = new TestRecord({key1: 123,  key2: '123'});
(record.key1: string); // Error number -> string
(record.key2: number); // Error string -> number
```

[Try this code on flowtype.org/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgAoCcCmALvgHYAmYC+YAFgIYBu1AlgLasCuhdARjPgDoASvgDGcXGVRkxMOgTBQOJUYWZwSYEeMkAKAJQAuMHRIBPANzpmJYrih1R1ACr4AzoQDKABzFgA3qhgYOIkHrgcqhK6Mg4cMIRuxgAknvS+ADyuHj5iAHxGYAxwzGQANEFgANb4ZgCMxiQcrDz4uBXBNWYATMbhNgDmFQC+VqihHmDZhNoSZMYAwnJublnuXr6ieWAAvFpic7qBnbUNYAAMHdW1vWAA5Hcj+mMk+EjTs3r+XWd13QDMZROPWMdz+-zuw2eYEwYAA8gBpVCvd7rT5kI4-YzgqEWGFYRHIt5TNEHL5dW5ggGQ6GwwlE1EedGYm7YgG4-FgACiuFwEgZJKZZIx31OoPBNLxsJ5fNwAo+wpZ9TZgOBlIlQK6-1BfDoNElnJl-OC4w0kwIOgoexRgpmitFyrA4KB1xB9wluNQugtcwEWLA-RIA1pWCNuDATRabTAAFptoGBl6fZI-ayI81WrgQ9zeRIA4RcINY9tI5mgA)